# Safari Plug-in SDK for iPhone OS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mobile-safari, safari-extension

Exists a way/SDK for developing plug-ins for mobile version of Safari browser on iPhone and/or iPad in Objective-C exists?

I have seen some possibilities for jailbroken devices ( http://www.macstories.net/news/yes-you-can-create-plugins-for-iphone-os/ ) but this is not an option for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot write plug-ins for Mobile Safari unless you are developing for jailbroken devices. There is no (public) API for it.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Any information that this might change in the future?